# ggplot and legend manipulation in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a dataset that has monthly averages of interest rate, years, and then I created a dummy variable to indicate the years begore 2016 (which will be the 0) and after that (which is the 1 in the dummy variable). I want to make a plot of the interest rate in time having one separate line according to the dummy variable (one for the years before 2016 and one after it). My code is:

```
p <- ggplot(data = dataset_new, 
       mapping = aes(x = month(Dates, label = TRUE), 
                     y = int_rate))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line(aes(group = factor(dummy),
                color = factor(dummy)))
p + theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill="lightblue", 
                                           size=0.5, linetype="solid"))
```

I would like to do two things next:

1. change the title of the legend from dummy to case study and
2. change the categories of the legend. What I mean is that now it writes 1 and 0, but I want to write (2017-2020) for the first and (2013-2016) for the second one.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the name:

```
+ labs(fill = 'Case Study')
```

To change the categories, I'd do it in the data:

```
dataset_new$case_study <- ifelse(dataset_new$dummy == 1, '(2017-2020)', '(2013-2016)')
```

And then in your ggplot call replace any instances of dummy with case_study.